# windows 10: How do I create symlinks to powershell scripts that can run inside powershell/Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, windows-10, symbolic-link

as above.

I tried:

- mklink soft link and it just opens the contents of the PS1 script inside notepad
- mklink hard link and it is asking for what app to use to open the file

Any ideas?

I'm just trying to replicate "ln -s" in linux.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like the normal result with `mklink` -- Windows always opens .ps1 files in Notepad by default, even if they're not symlinked.

Comment: Symbolic or hard links will always do the same thing the file “itself” does. Maybe you’re actually looking for Windows Shortcuts? They allow specifying a command line etc.